# Count number of identical values between two vectors

Tags: r

```
a<-c(19,24,34,47,47,47)
b<-c(3,14,24,25,47,47)
```

I want to know how many values in `a` match those in `b`, however i'm running into issues - when there are duplicate numbers present in both vectors. My desired answer for the above example would be `3` - because 24,47,47 - are shared between the two vectors.

If I use intersect:

```
intersect(a,b)

[1] 24 47
```

The 2nd matching 47 is ignored.

If I use %in%:

```
length(which(a %in% b))
[1] 4
```

The extra 47 in a is also counted.

I realise that I can do:

```
length(which(b %in% a))
[1] 3
```

However, I may also have cases where there is an extra matching value in b instead of a and so %in% is also not useful. For example:

```
a<-c(19,24,34,7,47,47)
b<-c(3,14,24,47,47,47)
length(which(b %in% a))
[1] 4 (I want the answer to still be 3)
```

So, without rearranging which vector comes first in the %in% function, for each test - I cannot figure out how to do this. Can somebody show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
sum(pmin(
  table(a[a %in% intersect(a, b)]),
  table(b[b %in% intersect(a, b)])
))
```

We make `table()`s of the chunks of `a`, `b` that are common to both, then we take the smallest numbers from those tables and add them up.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9317/how-to-get-common-values-between-two-multi-sets

I have a method to make it
Example:

`a <- c(19,24,34,47,47,47)`

`b <- c(3,14,24,25,47,47)`

`d <- intersect(unique(a), unique(b))`

`min(length(a[a %in% d]),length(b[b %in% d]))`

Using the min method to find.
Image: [Image Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsZ2P.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table` + `stack` like below

```
with(
    as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(list(a = a, b = b)))),
    sum((p <- pmin(a, b))[p > 0])
)
```

which gives

```
[1] 3
```

where

```
> as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(list(a = a, b = b))))
   a b
3  0 1
14 0 1
19 1 0
24 1 1
25 0 1
34 1 0
47 3 2
```